# jstl fmt:formatDate - hours/minutes/seconds dont'appear

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, jstl

I'm fetching date using JDBC Template from Postgres and showing them on the view in spring MVC using jstl and jsp.

Date is stored in Postgres database in format "Timestamp with timezone"
Example value read from database by myself: 2020-07-29 10:20:55.423+02

When I'm trying to show in in JSP using following instruction:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
```

Then it shows on the front

29-07-2020 00:00:00

Backing bean is type java.util.Date and i shouldn't change it.
What is the problem ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that shows how you retrieve it? My guess is that you retrieve a `java.sql.Date`, which is date-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are fetching the data via JDBC you should use `getTimestamp(String columnLabel)` that should return it with time.

See [ResultSet.getTimeStamp()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int%29)

Comment: Changing java backing bean datatype helped immediately without any further modifications.